# What's the best Kernel Regression package in R?

Tags: r, regression, nonparametric, software, kernel-smoothing

I am looking for a good and modern Kernel Regression package in R, which has the following features:

1. It has cross-validation
2. It can automatically choose the "optimal" bandwidth
3. It doesn't have random effect - i.e. if I run the function at different times on the same data-set, the results should be exactly the same...

I am trying "np", but I am seeing:

```
Multistart 1 of 1 |
Multistart 1 of 1 |
...
```

It looks like in order to do the optimization, it's doing multiple-random-start optimization ... Am I right?

Could you please give me some pointers?

I did some google search but there are so many packages that do this... I just wanted to find the best/modern one to use...

Comment: Even if the function used random numbers and the output could vary slightly you could always use set.seed to make sure the analysis was the same every time you ran it.

Answer (score 5):

Of course which one is the "best" depends on some rather subjective things, but  the `gam` command in the `mgcv` package meets all of the criteria you described.